# Null Pointer Exception on Array in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

The following code is returning a NullPointerException in Java. Can anyone clarify my mistake?

```
public void deposit2()
{
    BankAccounts[] accounts2 = new BankAccounts[10];
    accounts2[3].deposit();
}
```

Comment: You've declared an array of 10 BankAccounts, but they are not initialized. Initialize all the slots of the array .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
BankAccounts[] accounts2 = new BankAccounts[10];
```

is the same as

```
BankAccounts[] accounts2 = {null, null, null, ... null };  // (10 times)
```

You need to assign values to the elements of `accounts2` (or, at least to element 3) before you attempt to dereference them.

Comment: Unrelated: today I (hope to) get to legendary gold ... just saying thanks to all the folks I learned so much from ...

Answer (score 3):

Just declare it as you declared it in your code and after that use for loop to assign object reference to all index.

For example:

```
public void deposit2()
{
    BankAccounts[] accounts2 = new BankAccounts[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        accounts2[i] = new BankAccounts();
    }
    accounts2[3].deposite();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`BankAccounts[] accounts2 = new BankAccounts[10];` creates an object ie an array of bank accounts with 10 references that can point to 10 BankAccount objects,they are initailized to null , you need to create the actual bank objects , try this

```
BankAccounts[] accounts2 = new BankAccounts[10];

for(BankAccounts b:accounts2)//for each loop
{
b=new BankAccounts();
}
```